# How can I disable rollback in my Wix installer

Tags: wix

My installer hangs for nearly a minute before the progress bar starts going, and I'd like to eliminate that delay. I made a verbose log of the installation (below), and it's pretty clearly that the slow-down is in setting a restore point.

I'd happily sacrifice rollback capability. I see that there's even a DisableRollback element in the Wix schema. I can't get it to work, though. Presumably I just don't know how to use it correctly--I'm new to Wix and deployment concerns. How should I fix this?

Attempted:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">    
    <Product ...>
        <Package ... />
        <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />
        <UIRef Id="WixUI_Minimal" />

        <Feature ...>
            ...
        </Feature>

        <InstallExecuteSequence>
            <DisableRollback Before="InstallExecute" Overridable="no" />
        </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Relevant section of the log:

```
           ******* Product: C:\Users\mmorriso\Downloads\DevMDSetup.msi
           ******* Action: INSTALL
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (s) (3C:E8) [18:50:23:536]: Machine policy value 'DisableUserInstalls' is 0
MSI (s) (3C:E8) [18:50:23:571]: Machine policy value 'LimitSystemRestoreCheckpointing' is 0
MSI (s) (3C:E8) [18:50:23:571]: Note: 1: 1715 2: DevMD 
MSI (s) (3C:E8) [18:50:23:571]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (s) (3C:E8) [18:50:23:571]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1715 
MSI (s) (3C:E8) [18:50:23:571]: Calling SRSetRestorePoint API. dwRestorePtType: 0, dwEventType: 102, llSequenceNumber: 0, szDescription: "Installed DevMD".
MSI (s) (3C:E8) [18:51:35:485]: The call to SRSetRestorePoint API succeeded. Returned status: 0, llSequenceNumber: 323.
MSI (s) (3C:E8) [18:51:35:487]: File will have security applied from OpCode.
```

It's not a large installer--a couple dozen files, no custom actions, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest reading the Windows Installer MSDN topic:

[System Restore Points and the Windows Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372060(v=vs.85).aspx)

> Beginning with Windows Installer 5.0, the MSIFASTINSTALL property can
>   be set to prevent an installation from generating a system restore
>   point.

There are other possible tweaks also.

[DISABLEROLLBACK property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372899(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out MSIFASTINSTALL--that looks even better. What I'm looking for, though, is *how* to apply these properties.

Comment: <Property Id="MSIFASTINSTALL" Value="1" /> http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/property.html

Comment: Out of curiosity, why didn't `<DisableRollback Before="InstallExecute" Overridable="no" />` from the original question work?

Comment: It's a race condition thing. The DisableRollback action doesn't apply to the entire install only those things that are not yet scheduled. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368308(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: [**Adding a link to a serverfault.com answer**](https://serverfault.com/a/594661/20599) on the same topic.